# Keep Focus in Input Text Field, when showing a div using jquery .focusin

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to show a div when a user clicks in an input field, however, am having a couple of issues...

1) When the user clicks the input field, the div does show, however, any interaction with the div results in the div disappearing... how do I keep the field active while the user is interacting with the div?

2) I have more than one field, and using the code below... how do I set it to multiple field id's and show a div associated to each specific div (i.e. input field id=age shows div id=tip-age, input field id=height -- shows div id=tip-height)

I've crated a jsfiddle for this also http://jsfiddle.net/NEmYv/

HTML CODE

```
<form id="measure">
<div id="tip-age" style="display:none;">text here</div>
<input type="text" id="age" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("#age").focusin(function() {
    $("#tip-age").show();
}).focusout(function () {
    $("#tip-age").hide();
});
```

I do understand that this might be answered in the jQuery API... but I could really use your help on this matter.  My apologies in advance if this is a menial question...

Comment: ids should be unique.  But there are wild card selectors that allow you to select attributes/properties that contain certain strings/numbers http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ .  So using maybe input id=age then div id=divAge you can use wildcards to select the appropriate ones

Comment: Also when do you not want your div to display?  Or do you want it to display all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i created a demo to meet your requirements.  you can view the demo here:

[the fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/PeTUy/)
here's what i did:

```
$(".show-hidden-div").click(function() {
var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
$("#tip-"+inputId+"").show();});
```

as you can see, i created two inputs, each with a related hidden div. i added a class "show-hidden-input" so you can treat all related inputs with the click event using jquery.  once the input with the "show-hidden-input" class is clicked, i get the unique id and use it to find it's related hidden div.  i then show the related div.

Comment: That is perfect...just one more quick thought... how would I do it so that when i click on the next field, all the other divs would be hidden... (i.e. click on field one, field div 1 is shown, click on field 2, and field div 2 shown and field div 1 is hidden)

Comment: not a problem.  just add a class to the group of hidden divs and hide them whenever someone clicks an input.  [here's the updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/PeTUy/6/)